# How do I compare the means of 2 sets when they have different distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, normal-distribution

I want to compare the means of 2 sets of data. I have already taken the log and removed spurious outliers.

But the 2 sets have different shapes and I don't want to blindly throw them into a linear model.

Any tips?

One set is called liv and the other is called noliv. noliv is probably going to have a larger mean but using an appropriate test is the issue.

Is there any more general statistical test I can use here that doesn't assume normality. Obviously liv is normal but noliv isn't.

Even if the best answer is "take the log again", can someone please recommend a second best option to this?

[image: histogram of liv dataset]

[image: histogram of noliv dataset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare means, do not take logs first. $(1,4)$ has a larger mean than $(2,2)$, but $(\log 1,\log 4)$ has the *same* mean as $(\log 2, \log 2)$. You can easily find examples where the relation of means is swapped by taking logs.

The standard t test for equality of means only relies on the normal distribution of means, not on the normal distribution of the original data. And the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) yields that these means are indeed asymptotically normally distributed for most "reasonable" distributions of the original data. So I would use a t test on your data without a moment's hesitation.

Alternatively, you can run a [permutation test for equality of means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/361108/1352).

However, you apparently have quite a large sample, so even small deviations from equality will be statistically significant. You will need to decide whether these differences are "clinically" significant. [And whether means are the best way to look at your original question at all.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/361111/1352)

Comment: An excellent point about the central limit theorem. I wasn't aware. t-test is what I'll go with. I'm right in thinking that by taking the log then I'm comparing geometric mean? $(1,4)$ and $(2,2)$ have the same geometric mean and so their logs have the same arithmetic mean?

Comment: That is exactly right! (The geometric mean may well be what you are interested in. Just be sure to think about what you want.)

Comment: I was not particularly overwhelmed by the statement that you "removed spurious outliers". Unless they are actual measurement errors (or typos), I cannot see the rational for such intrusive redacting. What is your evidence for "spurious"?